# transformar blob em text e fazer função reversa depois

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando um script que resulta audio/video em formato blob, é preciso fazer o upload disso MAS gostaria de transformar ele em texto para que a execução de uma função a parte nao se prejudique. E quando ele chegar no servidor e retornar para um usuário que seja feito o efeito reverso transformando o texto em blob novamente para o usuário ter acesso a mídia, é possível fazer isso? como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`FileReader.readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL), ele codifica o `Blob` em base64. No seu servidor, você pode então decodificar da base64 para binário novamente (você não especificou a linguagem, mas todas costumam possuir rotinas prontas para fazer isso):

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64data = reader.result;                
    console.log(base64data);
}
```

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18650168/520779)</sup>

**Nota:** antes dos dados em base64, pode haver meta-dados sobre o conteúdo lido, por exemplo `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...`; o conteúdo portanto é aquilo depois de `base64,` - use somente essa parte ao decodificar no servidor (a menos que a função usada saiba tratar de *data urls*).